# HTML Homework that doesnt pass validation but displays fine

Tags: html

I was asked by the professor to use http://validator.w3.org/ this web site to validate my html file. It gives me errors.
The first error is:

> Line 1, Column 1: no document type
>   declaration; implying ""

Second error is:

> Line 11, Column 64: required attribute
>   "ALT" not specified  ✉  The
>   attribute given above is required for
>   an element that you've used, but you
>   have omitted it. For instance, in most
>   HTML and XHTML document types the
>   "type" attribute is required on the
>   "script" element and the "alt"
>   attribute is required for the "img"
>   element.
>   Typical values for type are type="text/css" for  and type="text/javascript" for .

Can anyone tell what is wrong? It displays just fine in my browser I am using IE 8. But the professor says if it fails in this validation check then the assignment is incomplete. Any help would be great.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Randy's first html web page !</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000066" text="#00ff44">

<h1 align="center"> Hello Professor</h1>
<h2 align="center"> By: Randy White</h2>
<p> I haven't done anything like this before.</p> 
<p> Seems to be ok</p> 
<p align="center"><img src="Koala.gif" width="100" height="100">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Day</th>
<th>Year</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>December</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2010</td>
</tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Line 1, Column 1: end of document in prolog 
✉ 
This error may appear when the validator receives an empty document. Please make sure that the document you are uploading is not empty, and report any discrepancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Randy's first html web page !</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000066" text="#00ff44">

<h1 align="center"> Hello Professor</h1>
<h2 align="center"> By: Randy White</h2>
<p> I haven't done anything like this before.</p> 
<p> Seems to be ok</p> 
<p align="center"><img src="Koala.gif" width="100" height="100" alt="koala image">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Day</th>
<th>Year</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>December</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2010</td>
</tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

i won't answer your questions but assuming you have to provide it tomorrow here you go.

Comment: Line 1, Column 1: end of document in prolog 
✉ 
This error may appear when the validator receives an empty document. Please make sure that the document you are uploading is not empty, and report any discrepancy.

Comment: well remove any trailing/preceding whitespaces

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a [doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) to top of HTML page, so that the browser understands what kind of document it is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This should make a few of other errors disappear. The remnant is pretty self-explaining. Add the required attributes and so on.

Comment: Your showing the html 5 doctype which is pretty cool but still not supported by all browsers, please keep this in mind! P.s the html should be uppercased.

Comment: @Michael: No, the `html` shouldn't (or at least doesn't need to) be upcased. The [working draft of the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-doctype) has it in lowercase but says that it is case insensitive.

Comment: @Michael: the HTML5 doctype is supported by all browsers from IE6 and up. Maybe you're confusing with the support of the w3 validator which is still "experimental" --but is decent enough, or maybe you're confusing with use of HTML5-specific elements like `<canvas>` and so on. But the OP's HTML doesn't contain any.

Comment: i gess i didnt type it the way i ment to say, html 5 specific features are not supported by all browsers yet. @Reese i didnt know it was case insensitive, the example show uppercase My bad!

Answer (score 2):

Inside of your img tag you need an alt tag...

`<img src='koala.jpg' alt='A Koala!'>`

An example of a document tag is this(taken from this very page)

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

The [w3c](http://www.w3.org/) has more info.

Answer (score 2):

For a valid HTML file you need a  tag before your HTML, it needs to be the first line.  See here for more information http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Second error: You need an alt="..." attribute in your img tag, this should be information pertaining to the image, in the case that the image is unavailable, or can't be seen by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [doctype](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html), and pass it through the w3c validator for the rest: [validator.w3.org/](http://validator.w3.org/)

The alt error is for your image.  alt attributes are required on [images](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.2).

Answer (score 0):

HTML is validated accordinng to XML (or SGML) rules. Browsers have been developed to accept non-conformant HTML, and so browsers are not a test of validity. Similarly there is good practice such as adding ALT attributes (for accessibility). Sighted humans don't need them but many others do.

Therefore it is always good practice to create conformant documents.